# Maximum and minimum of the function $xy+z^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Find the maximum and minimum values of the function $f(x,y,z)=xy+z^2$ in the circumference obtained by intersections between the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and the plane $y-x=0$.

I did Lagrange and found the points $(0,0,\pm2)$ I would call them maximum values and that the function have no minimum values. Not sure if that's correct... Thanks.

Edit: Lagrange calculations:

$\begin{cases}f_x\rightarrow y=4x\gamma\\
f_y\rightarrow x=0\\
f_z\rightarrow 2z=2z\gamma\\
2x^2+z^2=4
\end{cases}$

Comment: Please show us your Lagrange calculations.

Comment: I can't understand why if I calculate Lagrange with one constraint (being the intersection between two planes) I get a different result than if I do Lagrange with two constraints from the beginning...

Comment: There are two restrictions, so there are two Lagrange multipliers.  Or, eliminate $y$ from the start, and there is one Lagrange multiplier.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $x=y$ so you try to maximize/minimize $x^2+z^2$ with the constraint $2x^2+z^2=4$

But : $$x^2+z^2=4-x^2$$ so :

- $x^2+z^2$ is maximal when $x^2$ is minimal and this is at $x=0$ and $z=\pm 2$.
- $x^2+z^2$ is minimal when $x^2$ is maximal and this is at $x^2=2$ .This happens because : $$x^2 \leq \frac{1}{2} \cdot( 2x^2+z^2)=2$$  and this means that $x= \pm \sqrt{2}$ and $z=0$ .

The minimum is $2$ and it's achieved for $ \left (\pm \sqrt{2},\pm \sqrt{2},0 \right)$ and the maximum is $4$ achieved for $ \left (0,0,\pm 2 \right )$ .

Comment: Where did $x^2+z^2=4-z^2$ come from?

Comment: It should be $2x^2+z^2=4$ .I'll correct it .Thanks .

Comment: But the function I'm trying to maximize is $xy+z^2$

Comment: @JoãoPedro   Yes but you know that $x=y$ . This is one of the conditions  ..

Answer (score 0):

The Lagrange calculation as you've written it is mixing equations from both the one-constraint and two-constraint versions.

If you choose to combine the information from the spherical constraint ($ \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ + \ z^2 \ = \ 4 \ $ ) and the planar constraint ( $ \ y \ - \ x \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ y \ $ ) , the function to be extremized becomes $$ \ f(x,y,z) \ = \ xy \ + \ z^2 \ \ \rightarrow  \ \ \phi (x,z) \ = \ x^2 \ + \ z^2 \ \ , $$ subject to the single constraint $$ \ g(x,y,z) \ = \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ + \ z^2 \ = \ 4 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \gamma (x,z) \ = \ 2x^2 \ + \  z^2 \ = \ 4 \ \ . $$

The Lagrange equations $ \ \nabla \phi \ \ = \ \ \lambda \ \nabla \gamma \ $ are then

$$ \ \phi_x \ = \ \lambda \ \gamma_x \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2x \ = \ \lambda \ · \ 4x \ \ \ , \ \ \ \phi_z \ = \ \lambda \ \gamma_z \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2z \ = \ \lambda \ · \ 2z \ \ .  $$

It is generally not a good idea to solve such a system by simply cancelling factors across each equation; one should instead bring all terms to one side of each equation and consider the products of factors, thus:

$ ( \ 2 \ - \ 4 \lambda \ ) \ x \  =  \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \lambda \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ \ $ or $ \ \ x \  =  \ 0 \ \ . $  In the latter case, we have

$$ x \  =  \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ = \ x \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ z^2 \ = \ 4 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ z \ = \ \pm 2 \ \ , $$

while in the former case,

$$ \lambda \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  2z \ = \ \frac{1}{2}  ·  2z \ = \ z \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ z \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2x^2 \ = \ 4 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ \pm \sqrt{2} \ = \ y \ \ .  $$

Hence, there are four critical points, $  \ ( \ 0 \ , \ 0 \ , \ \pm 2 \ ) \ \ ,  $ at which  $ \ f \ = \ 2^2 \ = \ 4 \ \ , \ $  and  $ \ ( \ \pm \sqrt{2} \ , \ \pm \sqrt{2} \ , \ 0 \ ) \ \ , $  where $ \ f \ = \ (\pm \sqrt{2}) · (\pm \sqrt{2}) \ = \ 2 \ \ . $

$ $

Applying the two constraints individually, which then uses all three coordinate variables, we define the second constraint function $ \ h(x,y,z) \ = \ y \ - \ x \ = \ 0 \ \ . $  The corresponding Lagrange equations $ \ \nabla f \ \ = \ \ \lambda \ \nabla g  \ + \ \mu \ \nabla h \ $ are now

$$  f_x \ = \ y \ = \ \lambda \ · \ 2x \ + \ \mu \ · \ (-1) \ \ \ , \ \ \ f_y \ = \ x \ = \ \lambda \ · \ 2y \ + \ \mu \ · \ 1 \ \ \ , \ \ \  f_z \ = \ 2z \ = \ \lambda \ · \ 2z \ + \ \mu \ · \ 0  \ \ .  $$

This time, we'll start with the third equation, $ ( \ 2 \ - \ 2 \lambda \ ) \ z \  =  \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \lambda \ = \ 1 \ \ $ or $ \ \ z \  =  \ 0 \ \ . $  The latter case will bring us directly to the critical points $ \ ( \ \pm \sqrt{2} \ , \ \pm \sqrt{2} \ , \ 0 \ ) \ \ . $  The case for $ \ \lambda \ = \ 1 \   $ calls for a bit of "playing around" to find a satisfactory approach (as with other sorts of systems of equations, methods of solution are not always obvious).  The third equation, $ \ 2z \ = \ 1 · 2z \  $ leaves $ \ z \ $ unspecified for the moment.  The other equations become $ \ y \ = \ 1 · 2x \ - \ \mu \ $ and $ \ x \ = \ 1 · 2y \ + \ \mu \ \ . $  Solving for $ \ \mu \ $ gives us

$$ \mu \ \ = \ \ 2x \ - \ y \ \ = \ \ x \ - \ 2y \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \  = \  -y \ \ . $$

But our planar constraint requires that $ \ x \ = \ y \ $ , so it must be that $ \ \ x \ = \ y \ = \ 0 \ \ .  $  (This incidentally tells us that $ \ \mu \ = \ 0 \ $ , but we don't actually care about that any longer.)  The spherical constraint then produces the remaining critical points $  \ ( \ 0 \ , \ 0 \ , \ \pm 2 \ ) \ \ .  $

$ $

For this particular problem, a method along the lines of what **user252450** is much easier.  We could simply note that after "substituting" $ \ y \ = \ x \ $ , we are looking for the extrema of the "distance-squared" from the origin, $ \ x^2 \ + \ z^2 \ $ , of the points on the ellipse $ \ 2x^2 \ + \ z^2 \ = \ 4 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \frac{x^2}{( \sqrt{2})^2} \ \ + \ \ \frac{z^2}{2^2} \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ . $  The largest distance-squared of  $ \ 4 \ $ is reached for the endpoints $  \ ( \ 0  \ , \ \pm 2 \ ) \   $ of its major axis, with the smaller distance-squared of  $ \ 2 \ $ attained at the endpoints of its minor axis, $ \ (  \ \pm \sqrt{2} \ , \ 0 \ ) \ \ . $